# Meaning of 'Rorschach test'

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Source:  http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-opinion/responding-to-irom-sharmila/article8970888.ece

What is meant by the bold portion in this context

Reading the intent behind Ms. Sharmila’s decision to pick up the threads of a personal life ***is akin to a Rorschach test***.

Comment: Did you check the possible meanings for combination of "akin to" and "Rorschach test."?

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/psychoanalysis#psychoanalysis__2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strobbe's answer is correct on definition, but misses a nuance in how it is normally used in English.

A Rorschach test isn't just something open to interpretation, it is a test that *says more about **you** than it says about what you are evaluating*.

In context of your sentence, then, someone who says they know why Ms. Sharmila made her decision is telling us something about *themselves*, not something about Ms. Sharmila.

Answer (score 7):

The [Rorschach inkblot test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_test) uses ambiguous inkblots to examine a person's personality and emotional functioning. The inkblots don't have an "objective" meaning; the point of the test is to see what someone reads into them and to analyse these interpreations.

So when something is said to be akin (or similar) to a Rorschach test, that means that you can interpret it in various ways, depending on your point of view, or perhaps your personality, your emotional state, etc.